# Unable to login to SharePoint Online through CLI using Certificate

Tags: sharepoint-online, authentication, certificate

I am trying to authenticate into a SharePoint Online using the command prompt and Certificate instead of Username and Password.

I have read their official documentation [here](https://pnp.github.io/office365-cli/cmd/spo/login/).

The command to login using certificate is : `spo login https://contoso-admin.sharepoint.com --authType certificate --certificateFile /Users/user/dev/localhost.pfx --thumbprint 47C4885736C624E90491F32B98855AA8A7562AF1`

I have followed all the necessary steps such as :

1. Creating Azure AD App,
2. Generate  and Upload the Certificate to Azure AD,
3. and setting the 2 environment variables which are `OFFICE365CLI_AADAADAPPID` and `OFFICE365CLI_TENANT` on my computer .

and when I try to login I am getting the following error :

**SelfSignedJwt: ERROR: Failed to sign JWT. This is most likely due to an invalid certificate.**

I have no clue where is root cause of issue, but I am guessing it's due to the way I generate the certificate. The documentation has not provided any information about how to generate the certificate.

I have generated my certificate using the following command in PowerShell:

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -Subject "CN=CertSample" -CertStoreLocation "Cert:\CurrentUser\My" -KeyExportPolicy Exportable -KeySpec Signature -NotAfter (Get-Date).AddYears(2)
```

Comment: you will have to create it as mentioned [here](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell/tree/master/Samples/SharePoint.ConnectUsingAppPermissions)

Comment: same error at the end.

Comment: @Benjamin did you ever managed to fix this? If so, I'm very interested into how... Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Nsevens, do NOT waste your time trying this approach. I believe it's a Microsoft bug. I used PMP sharepoint instead and manage to get it done using that. PMP sharepoint support authentication using certificate.

Comment: @Benjamin I actually managed to get it working yesterday. :) https://github.com/pnp/office365-cli/issues/1066
Thank you for your reply though!

Comment: @Nsevens, that's great. thank you for sharing.